# how to split content on one page while first one displays first and other is hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display content on one page there are two parts of it so first content will display in full page while the other one is hidden the first content will time out after like 2 minutes and after 2 minutes the other part of the content will display below are sample of my code any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="top">
    *video will play in full screen on full page using javascript it will time out after 2 mininutes and it will hide the video and just show the the "Bottom" text *
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Lam6hufUt5k?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="bottom">*after 2 mins the text content will display on full page </div>
```

css

```
body {
width: 100% ;
height: 100% ;
margin: 0px ;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 100% working without jquery : ( you can see it working here : http://jsfiddle.net/akmozo/ws24yd9j/ )

Of course, you should keep in mind that hidding the iframe **does not stop playing the video** if it's playing. This is only an easy response for what you looking to do, It's working but you should ameliorate It to do things better.

**HTML code:**

```
<html><head>
<style>
    body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #top {
        position:absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #bottom {
        position:absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function load_timeout(){
        var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('top').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('bottom').style.display = 'block';
        }, 2000*60);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload='load_timeout()'>
<div id='top'>
    <iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lam6hufUt5k' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id='bottom'>*after 2 mins the text content will display on full page </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nothing is 100%. for example, in your demo the video keeps running and audio is still on

Comment: @CSᵠ I said "working 100%", It did what Sim is looking for according on what he said in his question, and in addition, if you've watched, I put a note in my answer that talks about what you say. I'm not writing a whole solution, just a way to resolve a problem and It's for the user to improve things to get the solution that he is looking for.

Comment: @akmozo it works 1000000000000000000%%%% not just 100% thank you soo muchhhhhh i really appreciate your help god bless :)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to hide the first and show the second after 2 minutes (120 seconds)

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("top").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("bottom").style.visibility = "initial";
    }, 1000*120);
</script>
```

Comment: Whoops. Editted answer.